# MyBatis 3.4.5; @SelectProvider not replacing parameter placeholders

Tags: java, mybatis

When I try to create dynamic query with MyBatis, the sql is generated successfully but parameters are not replaced in the SQL placeholders.

**Mapper @SelectProvider definition**

```
@SelectProvider(type = ActivitySqlProvider.class, method = "getActivitiesByUserAndType")
@ResultMap("activityResult")
List<Activities> getActivities(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("type") String type);
```

**ActivitySqlProvider class**

```
public String getActivitiesByUserAndType(final Map<String, Object> params) {

  String COLUMNS = "ACTIVITYID, USERID, TYPE, CREATED, DESCRIPTION";
  String TABLE_NAME = "ACTIVITY";

  boolean hasType = params.containsKey("type");

  final String sql = new SQL() {{
    SELECT(COLUMNS);
    FROM(TABLE_NAME);
    WHERE("USERID = #{userId}");

    if (hasType) {
      WHERE("TYPE = #{type}");
    }

  }}.toString();

  System.out.println(sql);
  return sql;
}
```

The SQL string is printed correctly and I can see the placeholders. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

A blind guess: you are using wrong `@Param` annotation.

Make sure you have:
`import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;`

and not:
`import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;`

Print the contents of the `params` map to validate this claim.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have imported the right package, the map contains the parameters that have been passed.

Comment: Probably this is not helpful, but I pasted your code as is and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh... Cool, thanks for checking it out. Appreciate it. Any configuration I might have missed out? Should the ActivitySqlProvider class be annotated or something?

Comment: No annotations on ActivitySqlProvider, @Mapper on ActivityMapper. I used mybatis-spring-boot-starter to wire it up quickly.

Comment: thank you for looking into this issue. I enabled logging and debugged the application and the issue was data related. The table that it was connected to had different set of records.